# How to remove sku and add another column from configurable product detail page

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, catalog, admin-panel

I need to edit configurable product grid view.
***Dashboard -> Catalog -> Product-> Add product(configurable product) or Edit(configurable product) ->Create Configuration or Edit Configuration -> Grid view.***

Here i need to remove sku column and add another column instead of this one.

How to edit these fields.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: in

```
Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\ConfigurablePane page,on

protected function getRows()
{
}
remove 'sku_container' => $this->getColumn('sku', __('SKU')),
```

and add

```
'oem_sku_container' => $this->getColumn('oem_sku', __('OEMSKU')),
                    'internal_sku_container' => $this->getColumn('internal_sku', __('INTERNALSKU')),
```

Step:2

In this page, `Magento\Ui\Component\Form`

on

```
 public function getDataSourceData()
    {
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
        $type_id =   $product->getTypeId();
        if($type_id ==  'configurable'){
            foreach ($data as $key_id => $data_value) {
                if (array_key_exists('configurable-matrix', $data_value)) {

foreach ($data_value['configurable-matrix'] as $configurableMatrixKey => $configurableMatrix) 
{
                        $sam_pid    =   $configurableMatrix['id'];
                        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

                        $productObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
                        ->load($sam_pid);

                        $product_oem_sku = $productObj->getOemSku();
                        $product_internal_sku = $productObj->getInternalSku();

                        $data[$key_id]['configurable-matrix'][$configurableMatrixKey]['oem_sku']      = $product_oem_sku;
                        $data[$key_id]['configurable-matrix'][$configurableMatrixKey]['internal_sku'] = $product_internal_sku;
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

modify grid.php at location

> {vendor}{theme}{Magento_Catalog}\Block\Adminhtml\Prduct

**Old code**

```
/*some code */

protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        parent::_prepareCollection();

        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'sku'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'attribute_set_id'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'type_id'
        )->setStore(
            $store
        );
/*some code */
```

New Code

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
parent::_prepareCollection();

$store = $this->_getStore();
$collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
    'description'
)->addAttributeToSelect(
    'name'
)->addAttributeToSelect(
    'attribute_set_id'
)->addAttributeToSelect(
    'type_id'
)->setStore(
    $store
);
/*some code */
```

protected function _prepareColumns(){

```
/* some code */ 
$this->addColumn(
    'sku',
    [
        'header' => __('SKU'),
        'index' => 'sku'
    ]
);
```

new code

```
protected function _prepareColumns(){
/* some code */ 
$this->addColumn(
    'description',
    [
        'header' => __('Descrption'),
        'index' => 'description'
    ]
);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it didn't works for me. I need to add attribute column to the product detail page. Not to the main grid.

Comment: If this answer work please approve it.

Comment: it doesn't work for me